# IFS9 (ERP system) help to create print layouts

Tags: layout, erp, ifs-erp

I am currently looking into creating our own print layouts for IFS9.
The only software I have available is IFS Report Designer, which isn't the most intuitive program.
IFS erp system does not have any real instructions manuals for it's users as it seems they are to keep all support internal.
I have above average IT knowledge, but nothing compared to you guys.
Does any one have Experience with the IFS9 erp system? can you provide any instructions or do you know of other software that you can recommend for creating print layouts, which would could work with this ERP system?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with IFS reports. But according to the following post, it supports several 3rd party report layouts including Crystal Reports.

http://ifshelpdesk.com/thread/alternatives-to-ifs-standard-report-layouts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience with IFS ERP system and it's print layouts (IFS calls these operational reports).

Yes the IFS report designer sucks.

In IFS 8 and prior you could use Crystal reports as alternative. In IFS 9 you can use either Crystal reports or SSRS, and both are way better than the IFS report designer. Either one of these will get the job done.

While I do like SSRS better for just about any other type of report, Crystal is a little better suited for designing reports that are specifically made to be printed. That being said, rumor has it that they will remove support for Crystal in IFS 10, and just have the option of IFS Report Designer or SSRS, so you might have to redesign these if and when you upgrade. This being the case SSRS is probably the best choice.

Setting up IFS to be able to use either of these, and developing them in IFS is too long to explain here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I'm now nearing completion for all the company's layouts, so I think I'll keep working with IFS report designer, as I have now gotten used to it's unintuitive controls and odd design choices. I'll look into SSRS if the need for better software becomes a must later on.